# Transforming level depth to subordinate count

Tags: python, parsing, tree

Let's consider this sample example text file:

```
Level: 1
Level: 1
Level: 2
Level: 2
Level: 2
Level: 3
Level: 3
Level: 1
Level: 2
Level: 2
Level: 1
```

I need to transform those lines using provided level data to subordinate count (excluding subordinates of subordinates)
The result should look like this:

```
:0
:3
:0
:0
:2
:0
:0
:2
:0
:0
:0
```

My first thought was transforming text file to XML and use simple xml parser technique as solution, but then I remembered that python sometimes can do magic things and thought to ask for advice if someone knows how to do this in "pythonic" way (without xml help)

Thanks

Comment: I can't get the logic on how the second list can be obtained from the first.

Comment: It's number of first child nodes for every node, simply put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
input_text = """Level: 1
Level: 1
Level: 2
Level: 2
Level: 2
Level: 3
Level: 3
Level: 1
Level: 2
Level: 2
Level: 1"""

# Parse input text into a list of levels (as int)
levels = []
for line in input_text.split('\n'):
    try:
        levels.append(int(line.split(': ', 1)[-1]))
    except Exception:
        pass # skip line

# Compute how many children each node has by counting the number of
# consecutive subsequent lines that belong to exactly the next level
counters = [0] * len(levels)
for i, level in enumerate(levels):
    for other in levels[i + 1:]:
        if other == level + 1:
            counters[i] += 1
        elif other == level:
            break

print '\n'.join(':%d' % c for c in counters)
```

Comment: In case, `(levels: 1,2,3,2)` it outputs `(1,1,0,0)` when it should `(2,1,0,0)`

Comment: Fixed! Replaced `else:` with `elif other == level:`.